# convert a string of time to 24 hour format

Tags: java, datetime, substring

I have a `string` holding a start time and an end time in this format `8:30AM - 9:30PM` I want to be able to strip out the `AM -` and the `PM` and convert all the times to 24 hour format so `9:30PM` would really be `21:30` and also have both the times stored in 2 different variables, I know how to strip the string into `substrings` but Im not sure about the conversion, this is what I have so far. the time variable starts out holding `8:30AM - 9:30PM`.

```
String time = strLine.substring(85, 110).trim();
//time is "8:30AM - 9:30PM" 

String startTime;               
startTime = time.substring(0, 7).trim();
//startTime is "8:30AM"

String endTime;
endTime = time.substring(9).trim();
//endTime "9:30AM"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working code (considering that you managed to split the Strings):

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(convertTo24HoursFormat("12:00AM")); // 00:00
        System.out.println(convertTo24HoursFormat("12:00PM")); // 12:00
        System.out.println(convertTo24HoursFormat("11:59PM")); // 23:59
        System.out.println(convertTo24HoursFormat("9:30PM"));  // 21:30
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
  // Replace with KK:mma if you want 0-11 interval
  private static final DateFormat TWELVE_TF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
  // Replace with kk:mm if you want 1-24 interval
  private static final DateFormat TWENTY_FOUR_TF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

  public static String convertTo24HoursFormat(String twelveHourTime)
        throws ParseException {
    return TWENTY_FOUR_TF.format(
            TWELVE_TF.parse(twelveHourTime));
  }
}
```

Now that I think about it, [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `H h K k` can be confusing.

Cheers.

Comment: I came back to this with another question, Im still using your method to convert the times, but I was wondering do you know how after I convert the time I could subtract an hour from it, I cant do it in the method cause Im only doing it for some times

Comment: Beef, I suggest that you open another question for it, but basicaly you can use `TWENTY_FOUR_TF.parse` with your String to obtain a `Date` object again, then send it to a `Calendar` using `calendar.setTime`. Subtract one hour with `calendar.add`, get the time back with `calendar.getTime` and use `TWENTY_FOUR_TF.format` to obtain the resulting `String`. So String (parse)-> Date -> Calendar -> Math Operations -> Date (format)-> String.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea but its not quite working right yet, I was going to open a new question but I thought I would try you first since you knew the method you wrote earlier in case I was to use it again

Answer (score 4):

You need to use: [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
And can refer this tutorial: [Formatting hour using SimpleDateFormat](http://www.java-examples.com/formatting-hour-using-simpledateformat)

Example:

```
//create Date object
Date date = new Date();

//formatting hour in h (1-12 in AM/PM) format like 1, 2..12.
String strDateFormat = "h";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

System.out.println("hour in h format : " + sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel (unless you are doing this as a school project or some such).

Just get a date object out of your time stamp and then you can generate whatever format you want with this: [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[edited to address your specific request]
if you absolutely need to work from your own unique strings, then you'll do something like this (I don't know exactly what your strings look like... you're using offsets like 85, which means nothing out of context).

I didn't check this for bugs, but this is approximately what you want...

```
myStr = timestampString.toLowerCase(); //something like 8:30am
boolean add12 = (myStr.indexOf("pm") != -1)?true:false;

//convert hour to int
int hour = Integer.parseInt(myStr.split(":")[0]);

int minutes = Integer.parseInt(  myStr.split(":")[1].replaceAll("\\D+","").replaceAll("^0+","") ); //get the letters out of the minute part and get a number out of that, also, strip out leading zeros

int militaryTime = hour + (add12)? 12:0;
if(!add12 && militaryTime == 12)
 militaryTime = 0; //account for 12am

//dont' forget to add the leading zeros back in as you assemble your string
```

Comment: well I read these times from a text file and thats why they get read together in substring and then get placed into 2 other substrings, cause I need to convert them to 24hour time and then Ill be using a ODBC to put them into the database, the text file holds a couple hundred different start and end times in order to do some scheduling

Comment: I explained what my `time` variable was holding so I didnt think people would need to worry about my offsets

Answer (score 2):

With [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html), the code looks like:

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter12 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("K:mma");
        DateTime begin = formatter12.parseDateTime(beginTime);
        DateTime end = formatter12.parseDateTime(endTime);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter24 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("k:mma");
        String begin24 = formatter24.print(begin);
        String end24 = formatter24.print(end);
```

Answer (score 2):

I should like to contribute the modern answer

```
    DateTimeFormatter twelveHourFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String time = "8:30AM - 9:30PM";
    String[] times = time.split(" - ");
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(times[0], twelveHourFormatter);
    System.out.println(start.toString());
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(times[1], twelveHourFormatter);
    System.out.println(end.toString());
```

This prints:

```
08:30
21:30
```

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. The `SimpleDateFormat` class used in many of the other answers is long outdated and was always troublesome. `java.time` is so much nicer to work with than the date-time classes from the 1990’s. A `LocalTime` is a time of day without a date (and without time zone), so suits your need much better than an old-fashioned `Date`.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

24 hour time adds 12 to any time greater than 12pm so that 1pm is 13 and so on until 24 or 12am. Here is the sudo code:

```
if(hour <= 12)
{
  hour = hour + 12;
}
```

Comment: I understand how to do it, just not how to code it without using `substrings` to check whether its am or pm and then getting a `substring` of for the time before the AM or PM and then having to convert that time, I feel it will make me have an unnecessary amount of `substrings` @ToddMoses

Answer (score 1):

All the below lines will works when 
String str="07:05:45PM";
and when you call timeConversion(str) and want to convert to 24 hours format..

```
 public class TimeConversion {

  private static final DateFormat TWELVE_TF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ssa");
      private static final DateFormat TWENTY_FOUR_TF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");


     static String timeConversion(String s) {

         String str = null;
         try {
            str= TWENTY_FOUR_TF.format(
                        TWELVE_TF.parse(s));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return str;

     }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String str="07:05:45PM";

        System.out.println(timeConversion(str));


    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.