# How to set time to 24 hour format in Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I need to set the time on the current date. The time string is always in 24 hour format but the result I get is wrong:

```
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
  Date d1 = df.parse("10:30");
  Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
  c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, d1.getHours());
  c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, d1.getMinutes());
```

The date should be today's date and the time set to 10:30. Instead the time in c1 ends up being 22:30. How can I force the calendar control to recognize my time is 24 hour format?

**EDIT:**
If I just do this:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
```

This gives me the same result. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435005/convert-a-string-of-time-to-24-hour-format

Comment: setTime takes a Date. The date will end up overwriting the calendar's date.

Comment: My time is ALWAYS in 24 hour format. That posting clearly indicates am/pm format.

Comment: `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` methods are deprecated. And it looks like you don't need to use them. What happens if you just pass 10 and 30 to `Calendar` setters?

Comment: I just tried that and that gives me the same result. Clearly something stupid going on with the Calendar object.

Answer (score 199):

Replace this:

```
c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, d1.getHours());
```

with this:

```
c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, d1.getHours());
```

Calendar.HOUR is strictly for 12 hours.

Comment: +1 Javadoc says it very clear "Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22."

Comment: I have been trying to solve an issue the whole day and you saved me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 11):

use  `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");` instead

**UPDATE**

@Ingo is right. is's better use `setTime(d1);`

first method `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` is now deprecated

I test this code

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
  Date d1 = df.parse("23:30");
  Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  c1.setTime(d1);
  System.out.println(c1.getTime());
```

and output is ok `Thu Jan 01 23:30:00 FET 1970`

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm aa");
  Date d1 = df.parse("10:30 PM");
  Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
  c1.setTime(d1);
  String str = sdf.format(c1.getTime());
  System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Same result. I still end up with 22:30.

Comment: You are using 23:30. Try 10:30. If your substituting 10:30 gives you 10:30, then it tells me that it probably is a platform issue.

Comment: may be I don't understand what you want but look at my last example

Comment: As I posted, my time is ALWAYS 24 hours. 10:30 is 10:30 in the morning and not in the evening as you have done. I don't use am/pm.

Comment: so if I set 10.30 in sysout I have 10.30 if I set 22.30 in sysiut I have 22.30

Answer (score 6):

You can set the calendar to use only AM or PM using

> calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, int);

0 = AM

1 = PM

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

if you replace in the function SimpleDateFormat("hh")
with ("HH")
will format the hour in 24 hours instead of 12.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using fullcalendar on my project recently, I don't know what exact view effect you want to achieve, in my project I want to change the event time view from 12h format from

[image]

to 24h format.

[image]

If this is the effect you want to achieve, the solution below might help:

set         `timeFormat: 'H:mm'`

Answer (score 1):

Here you will get all kinds of time related problems. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        // To get the current hour
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        System.out.println("hour: " + hour);

        // To get the current time in 12 hours format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.US);
        String a = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Time: " + a);

        // To get the desired time in 12 hours format from 23 hours format
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.ENGLISH);
        String a1 = sdf1.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Time: " + a1);

        /*  H Hour in day (0-23) 
            k Hour in day (1-24) 
        */

        //To get the desired time in 24 hours format as 0-23 or 1-24
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm",Locale.ENGLISH);
        String a2 = sdf2.format(cal.getTime());
        String a3 = sdf3.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Time: " + a2);
        System.out.println("Time: " + a3);

        //For example, time like 12:30 PM. How can i convert to 24 hours time in java?

        SimpleDateFormat bigFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat smallFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = smallFormat.parse("12:30 AM");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
        System.out.println(smallFormat.format(date) + " = " + bigFormat.format(date));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

private void setClock() {

```
    Timeline clock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int  hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        eski_minut = minute;
        if(second < 10){

            time_label.setText(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":0" + second);

        }else if (minute < 10){
            time_label.setText(hour + ":0" + (minute) + ":0" + second);

        }
        else {
        time_label.setText(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);}
    }),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
    );
    clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    clock.play();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
```

Or

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm");
```

Reference : [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Neither of those work. Same result: 22:30. They need to rename SimpleDateFormat to ComplexAndStupidDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.parse( "10:30" )  // Parsed as 24-hour time.
```

## java.time

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar` that are now supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalTime`

The java.time classes provide a way to represent the time-of-day without a date and without a time zone: `LocalTime`

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 10 , 30 );  // 10:30 AM.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 22 , 30 );  // 22:30 is 10:30 PM.
```

### ISO 8601

The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when generating and parsing strings. These formats use 24-hour time.

```
String output = lt.toString();
```

> LocalTime.of( 10 , 30 ).toString() : 10:30
>
> LocalTime.of( 22 , 30 ).toString() : 22:30

So parsing `10:30` will be interpreted as 10:30 AM.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "10:30" );  // 10:30 AM.
```

### `DateTimeFormatter`

If you need to generate or parse strings in 12-hour click format with AM/PM, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Tip: make a habit of specifying a `Locale`.